# Добавить таблицу со статистикой к графику

Tags: r

У меня есть график построенный следующим образом

```
library(ggplot2)

x <- sort(rnorm(1000))
y <- rnorm(1000)
z <- rnorm(1000) + atan2(x, y)

dt <- data.frame(x, y, z)
g <- ggplot(dt, aes(x = x, y = y))

g <- g + geom_point(aes(color = z)) + scale_color_gradient(low="blue", high="red")

plot(g)
```

Я хочу над графиком добавить таблицу с небольшой статистикой: всего точек, точек со значением `z < -1`, точек со значениями `-1 <= z <= 1`, точек со значением `z > 1`.
Пробовал добавлять таблицу через `annotation_custom()`, но получается слишком криво. Может быть есть какие-то ещё способы добавить таблицу над графиком?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал при помощи библиотеки `gridExtra`. Возможно, есть более простое решение. Если так, то буду рад, если кто-нибудь поделится, пока приведу своё.

Считаем число точек в нужных интервалах и собираем матрицу

```
all <- length(z)
z1 <- length(z[z < -1])
z2 <- length(z[z >= - 1 & z <= 1])
z3 <- length(z[z > 1])

stat <- matrix(c(all, z1, z2, z3),ncol=4,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(stat) <- c("Всего", "(...;-1)", "[-1; 1]", "(1; ...)")
```

С помощью `tableGrob` делаем таблицу

```
table <- tableGrob(stat, rows = NULL)
```

Указываем сколько частей на холсте какой график будет занимать, т.е. таблица -- 1/6, график -- 5/6.

```
lay <- rbind(c(1),
             c(2),
             c(2),
             c(2),
             c(2),
             c(2))
```

Строим таблицу и график

```
grid.arrange(table, g, layout_matrix = lay)
```

Результат:

[image: График]

Comment: Вот более няшный вариант https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40335838/adding-a-table-to-ggplot-figure

Comment: Да, я пробовал так делать, проблема в том, что, если на графике мало пустого пространства, то таблица перекрывает часть точек. Либо надо увеличивать площадь графика.